# Can Btrfs use SSD for metadata and leave bulk data on HDD?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext3, xfs, btrfs

is it possible for Btrfs to use SSD for metadata only & leave bulk data on less costly storage such as HDD? I refered to this page [Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices) and can not find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It would say it cannot at this time, but it would be very interesting to know if this is somewhere in the roadmap!

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with using bcache to combine ssd and hdd as the backing device for btrfs. The cache hit ratio varies by workload, but can be quite nice and can be monitored via /sys/fs/bcache

Comment: I'm writing and reading lots of data and often find essential metadata, such as what is needed to mount the filesystem (btrfs here) or to do "ls" in a large, often used folder not in the cache. I assume that's because bcache doesn't see the most recent usage when the respective blocks are cached in memory.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is currently not possible.